# Every map $S^1 \rightarrow X$, extends to a map $D^2 \rightarrow X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reviewing some solutions for past papers for an upcoming exam, and I am a bit confused with the solution for this question. I am hoping someone can shed some light for me:

I want to prove that:

> Every map $S^1 \rightarrow X$ is homotopic to a constant map
>   $\implies$ Every map $S^1 \rightarrow X$, extends to a map $D^2 \rightarrow X$

Now the solutions state that:

> if $h: S^1 \times I \rightarrow X$ is a homotopy taking a map $f:S^1
>  \rightarrow X$ to a constant map, then $h$ factors through the
>   quotient $S^1 \times I/S^1 \times \{1\}$
>
> i.e. $h$ is equal to the composition $S^1 \times I \rightarrow S^1
>  \times I/S^1 \times \{1\} \rightarrow X$
>
> where the first map is the quotient map.
>
> The pair $(S^1 \times I/S^1 \times \{1\}, S^1 \times I)$ is
>   homeomorphic to $(D^2,S^1)$, and the map above gives a map $D^2
>  \rightarrow X$ such that the restriction to $S^1$ is equal to $f$.

I'm not quite sure I understand the quotient $I/S^1$. I know $S^1$ can be constructed as a quotient of the interval $[0,1]$, but what is $I/S^1$? Do we just 'quotient' off all the points in the interval $[0,1]$ except for the endpoints?

I'm also not understanding how the map: $S^1 \times I \rightarrow S^1
 \times I/S^1 \times \{1\} \rightarrow X$

gives a map from $D^2 \rightarrow X$ where the restriction to $S^1$ is equal to $f$.

Would greatly appreciate any help to understand this. Thanks so much.

Comment: the paranthesis are misleading, it should read:
$(S^1 \times I)/(S^1 \times \{1\})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nactusraid said in the comments, the parentheses are incorrect.  The idea is that if you collapse one boundary component of an annulus ($S^1 \times I$) to a point, you get a space that is homeomorphic to $D^2$ and the homeomorphism takes the other boundary component to $\partial D^2 = S^1$.

There is an easy  point set topology theorem that says that if you have a continuous function $f \colon X \to Y$  and a quotient map $g \colon X \to Z$ such that $f$ is constant on the fibers of $g$, there exists a map $h \colon Z \to Y$ with $f = h \circ g$.

Applying this to your situation, you  have a homotopy $h \colon S^1 \times I \to X$ between $f$ and a constant map.  The above theorem gives you a continuous map from $g \colon (S^1 \times I) / (S^1 \times \{1\}) \to X$.  Since $h$ restricted to $S^1 \times \{0\}$ is equal to $f$, you see that $g$ restricts to $f$.