# Critic for a proof of a part on problem Hatcher's 1.1.5

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

> Show that if every map $S^1 \to X$ is homotopic to a constant map, then every map $S^1 \to X$ extends to a map $D^2 \to X$.

I've seen a few solutions for this questions on the site, but none of which employs that the cone over $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$.

I'm seeking critic for the following proof I constructed.

Let $f:S^1 \to X$ and suppose that $f$ is homotopic to a constant map. That is there exists $h:S^1 \times I \to X$ such that $h(x,0)=f$ and $h(x,1)=c_{x_0}$ for $x_0 \in X$.
Now define $h': C(S^1)  \to X$ as $h'(\{x,t\})=h(x,t)$ for $t \in [0,1)$ and $h'(S^1 \times \{1\})=c_{x_0}$. The diagram

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,S^1 \times I \\
\\
q \downarrow & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\searrow \,{h} \\
\\
C(S^1) & \xrightarrow{h'}  & X
\end{array}$$

commutes since $h(x,1)=c_{x_0}$ for every $x \in S^1$. Now for every $x \in S^1 \times \{0\}$ we have that $h'(\{x,0\})=h(x,0)=f$ and since $C(S^1) \approx D^2$ the map $h':C(S^1) \to X$ is a continuous extension for $f$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739172/every-map-s1-rightarrow-x-extends-to-a-map-d2-rightarrow-x?rq=1) employs that the cone over $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$. It also states an actual definition for $C(S^1)$, albeit one with a typographical error that seems to be the main issue of the post.